# val procedure, got "untyped", expected "Real" in Pascal

Tags: types, syntax, pascal

What's wrong with Pascal? FPC says that there's a mistake in this line: Got "untyped", expected "Real".

```
p(val(ParamStr(2), par_a), val(ParamStr(3), par_b));
```

But there's no mistake, par_a and par_b are both real.

```
var par_a, par_b, par_c, par_d, x1, x2, x3: real;
```

Before that I used double instead of real. I thought the mistake was that val() wants to get a 'real' parameter. But it doesn't work.

What does it mean 'Untyped'?

Comment: Basically read the "untyped" as C's void, iow not a function. Then it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
val(ParamStr(2), par_a);
val(ParamStr(3), par_b);
p(par_a, par_b);
```